# Python: urllib.parse.urljoin VS string concatenation

Tags: python, url

Could you please explain to me the difference between two approaches of url formatting : concatenation and  urllib.parse.urljoin and which is better to use?

```
# base_url = "http://example.com"
# url_path = "/ssome/endpoint"
from urllib.parse import urljoin
url = urljoin(base_url, url_path)
```

VS

```
url = base_url + url_path
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you read the description of `urljoin` and looked at the examples…? https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin

Comment: @deceze, of course and I still don't understand in which case I should use urljoin , but in which - string concatenation. If you get some good advice, I will be grateful to you.

Comment: In a nutshell, `urljoin` basically works like a browser. If you have a relative link `<a href="foobar">` in a browser, the browser will resolve the absolute URL relative to the current URL it's on. That's basically what `urljoin` does. — String concatenation just, well, concatenates two strings exactly as given.

Comment: @deceze, than you. My question is what the "pythonic way"? So, if I get task to build url from existing base and endpoint, should I use urljoin or string concatenation. Probably in this case it makes no difference what to use, but possibly (on some data) this will lead to erroneous behavior

Comment: In this particular case, yeah, no difference. Use the simplest thing that gets the job done for you…

Comment: @deceze, thank you very much. This is the answer on my question!